# Caching / Security Issue

Tags: security, http, caching, https

Recently when I logged in to view my account on a very well-known mobile phone operators' site I was presented with an entirely unrelated account. After I refreshed the page I was shown the correct account.

It wasn't cached from a previous session as other users do not use the machine.

I understand that the exact reason for why this happened can't be discovered but rather I'm asking of *which possible ways* this situation can happen.  I can only think of a caching issue on the network, which mistakenly passed me the page of someone else who recently used the site.

What other possible ways may the described situation happen?  Why is this possible?  Is this not something to be worried about?

Comment: Plusnet - Could this be an ISP issue?  If so how?

Comment: You could consider cross-posting this to security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for any other platform but in ASP.NET there's a technique that can lead to something like this, which is output caching. Once an incoming request has been completely processed and rendered by the web server, the generated HTML is cached in memory on the server, and any further requests *that the server considers to be for the same page*, are fulfilled by the cached version of the page.

It's a powerful technique for increasing the scalability of a site but you've got to be careful how you apply it (and test it!) or else you end up in this sort of situation where people start seeing details of other people's accounts - I've heard of this happening on banking sites.

How do you fix it? In the `OutputCache` page directive, there's a number of `VaryBy...` attributes that can be set to control the set of circumstances under which the server generates a new version of the page vs serving the request from the cache e.g. caching a page for each unique querystring, caching pages based on content encodings. In ASP.NET WebForms, there's also a little-known control called `Substitution` which allows you to dynamically insert content into an output-cached page.

MSDN References

- [OutputCache page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx)
- [Subsitution control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228212.aspx)

Comment: Good idea - could well be the reason